# How to overcome Django error - [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'core.wsgi': No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, apache, importerror

I am having issues setting up my Django app onto AWS using Lambda and API gateway. Here is my application configuration:

1. The Django app I have created is a simple automation dashboard with the project being core and an app called data
2. The data app has a few charts and the information for the charts flow from the SQLite db.
3. The website gets loaded successfully when I run `python manage.py runserver`.  I am able to access the site locally from http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
4. Most of the components were built based on the setup explained [here](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-charts/).
5. The app is configured with a virtual env as mentioned in the above link except my python version is 3.11.4. The `mod_wsgi` version is 5.0.0.
6. I have setup the lambda and API gateway onto an AWS account using SAM. Here is the template.yaml file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Description: Automation Backlog dashboard django app on AWS Lambda

Resources:
  automationbacklogdashboard:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: core.wsgi.application
      Runtime: python3.11
      CodeUri: /Users/arjunvijayakumar/Desktop/workspaces/automation-backlog-dashboard
      MemorySize: 256
      Timeout: 30
      Events:
        QAAutomationBacklogDashboard:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: ANY
```

Problem:

1. When I run `sam local start-api`, the application starts successfully.
2. When I access the URL provided http://127.0.0.1:3000/ I get the following error:

```
(env) arjunvijayakumar@V536M7J663 automation-backlog-dashboard % sam local start-api
Mounting automationbacklogdashboard at http://127.0.0.1:3000/ [DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT]
You can now browse to the above endpoints to invoke your functions. You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions,
changes will be reflected instantly/automatically. If you used sam build before running local commands, you will need to re-run sam build for the
changes to be picked up. You only need to restart SAM CLI if you update your AWS SAM template
2023-12-14 19:38:31 WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000
2023-12-14 19:38:31 Press CTRL+C to quit
Invoking core.wsgi.application (python3.11)
Local image is up-to-date
Using local image: public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11-rapid-x86_64.

Mounting /Users/arjunvijayakumar/Desktop/workspaces/automation-backlog-dashboard/.aws-sam/build/automationbacklogdashboard as
/var/task:ro,delegated, inside runtime container
START RequestId: d3ff90a3-f56b-43c2-9574-5c356e6b0270 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'core.wsgi': No module named 'django'
Traceback (most recent call last):
END RequestId: 16366494-94fa-44d0-ab96-0dad422187a2
REPORT RequestId: 16366494-94fa-44d0-ab96-0dad422187a2  Init Duration: 0.31 ms  Duration: 262.91 ms Billed Duration: 263 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 256 MB

Lambda returned empty body!
Invalid lambda response received: Invalid API Gateway Response Keys: {'requestId', 'stackTrace', 'errorMessage', 'errorType'} in {'errorMessage':
"Unable to import module 'core.wsgi': No module named 'django'", 'errorType': 'Runtime.ImportModuleError', 'requestId':
'16366494-94fa-44d0-ab96-0dad422187a2', 'stackTrace': []}
2023-12-14 19:40:01 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Dec/2023 19:40:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 -
2023-12-14 19:40:01 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Dec/2023 19:40:01] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 -
```

What I have tried:

1. I added the following lines to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/arjunvijayakumar/Desktop/workspaces/automation-backlog-dashboard/core/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /Users/arjunvijayakumar/Desktop/workspaces/automation-backlog-dashboard/env
WSGIPythonPath /Users/arjunvijayakumar/Desktop/workspaces/automation-backlog-dashboard/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages

<Directory /Users/arjunvijayakumar/Desktop/workspaces/automation-backlog-dashboard/core>
  <Files wsgi.py>
    Order deny,allow
    Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

Restarted the apache server using `sudo apachectl restart`

2. I tried setting the uwsgi server as follows  (tried both 8000 and 3000 ports):

```
(env) arjunvijayakumar@V536M7J663 automation-backlog-dashboard % uwsgi --http :3000 --module core.wsgi --virtualenv /Users/arjunvijayakumar/Desktop/workspaces/automation-backlog-dashboard/env
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.23 (64bit) on [Mon Dec 18 08:53:48 2023] ***
compiled with version: Apple LLVM 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5) on 15 December 2023 04:29:17
os: Darwin-23.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.2.0: Wed Nov 15 21:55:06 PST 2023; root:xnu-10002.61.3~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6020
nodename: V536M7J663.local
machine: arm64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 12
current working directory: /Users/arjunvijayakumar/Desktop/workspaces/automation-backlog-dashboard
detected binary path: /Users/arjunvijayakumar/Desktop/workspaces/automation-backlog-dashboard/env/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 5333
your memory page size is 16384 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 256
lock engine: OSX spinlocks
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :3000 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 71120)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:57612 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 3.11.4 (v3.11.4:d2340ef257, Jun  6 2023, 19:15:51) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
PEP 405 virtualenv detected: /Users/arjunvijayakumar/Desktop/workspaces/automation-backlog-dashboard/env
Set PythonHome to /Users/arjunvijayakumar/Desktop/workspaces/automation-backlog-dashboard/env
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x106462b10
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72896 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
3.11.4 (v3.11.4:d2340ef257, Jun  6 2023, 19:15:51) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
/Users/arjunvijayakumar/Desktop/workspaces/automation-backlog-dashboard/env
/Users/arjunvijayakumar/Desktop/workspaces/automation-backlog-dashboard/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x106462b10 pid: 71119 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 71119, cores: 1)
```

I still keep getting the `[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'core.wsgi': No module named 'django' error`.

3. I am unable to locate the `mod_wsgi.so` file to run the `ldd` command to verify the python versions. There is no file `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197829/mod-wsgi-so-cannot-load-mod-wsgi-so-into-server-libpython2-5-so-1-0-cannot-op). The closest I could find was `/usr/sbin/httpd` and httpd is a file and not a folder.
4. Tried setting the PYTHONPATH as `export PYTHONPATH=/Users/arjunvijayakumar/Desktop/workspaces/automation-backlog-dashboard/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages` inside the virtual env. (No avail).

Can anyone provide me recommendations to overcome this error?

Thanks in advance.